# Creating a graph in R with a timeline in the x-axis

Tags: r

I have been trying to graph a  dataset using a variable which is defined as time and contains the times when the samples were obtained. I have been trying to graph this in R using ggplot2, but I need that the x-axis only to contain the hours from 8 pm to 8 am in that order. R by default orders the x-axis from 12 am to 11 pm. Any insight on how to edit this in R, or how to come up with a graph that helps me achieve what I want?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post a reproducible example of your data, like `dput()` if you can.

Comment: What data are you working with and what have you tried? An R question that is [easy to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) contains, at a minimum, a representative sample of data, the code that's causing a problem, and a detailed description of the desired output